# How can I add "Show desktop" docklet to docky?

Tags: docky

I have some missing docklets in docky I used to use before. The most important one I remember is "Show desktop" which is important for me. I tried removing and installing it several times but no use I can't find it in the docklet's part of the settings.

I tried searching for something like docky-extras in aptitude and synaptic package manager and tried different terms and combination but seems like there is no such thing.

So how can I add the missing docklet?

Comment: What version of Docky are you using? Did you just install docky on a new ubuntu install?

Comment: I am using 2.0.7-1. Just typed sudo aptitude install docky in terminal. I think the first time though i downloaded a package from somewhere I can't remember.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Desktop Docklet](http://wiki.go-docky.com/index.php?title=Desktop_Docklet) was added in the Docky **2.1.x**  series, which can
be installed via the [Docky Development PPA](https://launchpad.net/~docky-core/+archive/ppa).

This is development software so use at your own risk!

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:docky-core/ppa`
`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install docky`

Comment: Pushing users to a devel PPA isn't smart IMO. The PPA page says it all: "Beta testing anything here is like walking into a burning building. We wont stop you, but you will probably get cooked alive." Not safe for general consuption.

Comment: @Oli 2.0.7 is the latest official release so if the OP remembered having that Docklet he was already using an unstable release.

Answer (score 2):

Well despite there being news of there being a show-desktop helper [in March](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/03/docky-gets-show-desktop-docklet/), I can't see it in the current Ubuntu version (v2.0.7-1). The old method still stands though... And I've spent a minute making it a whole lot easier.

1. Install `wmctrl`: `sudo apt-get install wmctrl`
2. Create a new launcher on the desktop (right click the desktop -> Create Launcher...) and as the command, enter:

   ```
   bash -c "if wmctrl -m | grep 'mode: ON'; then exec wmctrl -k off; else exec wmctrl -k on; fi"
   ```

   Set the icon you'd like it to have in docky, give it a nice name, etc. Click okay.
3. Drag the launcher onto Docky. Now you can delete the launcher from the desktop.